# CSS Responsive Height Fail

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design

Simple Set Up:

Parents are HTML and BODY their CSS

```
html body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
min-height: 100%;
min-width:100%;
background-color:blue;
}
```

I want a div to have a responsive height:

```
#test {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I should see yellow (I thought I should), but I only see blue.  Sorry for the extremely basic question, I've never had this problem, and I don't know why it just started happening...

How can I have a responsive height for #test?  Shouldn't this be working?  I am using ruby on rails, could this be why?

I have the standard application.html.erb and the only div I have on my view is the test.

Sure, it's in rails so my view is just

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

The application.html.erb explicitly looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FooPartners</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

So the browser interprets as html,body, test, and then closes them.

*Update:* I got this working by changing the height to

```
height: 12(orWhatever%)vh;
```

is this advisable, how come this is the only way I can get this working.

Comment: Can you post your application.html.erb and view?

Comment: You actually should have some heights on the html AND body set. So html,body { height: 100%; width: 100%; } and then as long as your div is a child of the body you could set a min-height of whatever% or just inherit - http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/ojzKv

Comment: My css is html, body.  That gets both of them to 100%, no? I'm seeing a full page of blue.

Comment: @Evan the css posted works for me without setting height and width explicitly, so i think something else might be going on.

Comment: @D-Jones, Where do you have it up? http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/ojzKv. Body is going to look to HTML on how to scale, the css provided is strictly for the body

Comment: @Peege151 what browser are you using? the code works fine in ie11 but not in ie8

Comment: so you're serving it up locally, why? just open it with chrome. also, create a pen or a fiddle if you're able to get something with yellow working.

Comment: The codepen is blue too, so it's not just me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORIGINAL Question:

[image]You have `html body` and it should be `html, body`

The syntax is incorrect.

## You are missing a comma.

http://jsbin.com/zizuse/1/edit

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ghCLH

```
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:blue;
}


#test {
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the comma, as well as explicitly defining each on their own, to no avail.

Comment: This is correct syntax, a comma between selectors. And it works on in the CodePen and Bin.

Comment: It was because I had MIN-HEIGHT in the html, body declarations.  I had tried with the ',' in there but I had not includuded it in my question...Anyways, Thank You!